# Pull Entire Module into current scope Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, commonjs

I'm trying to pull an entire module into the current scope of another file after a require call.

For instance if my module looks like this:

```
exports.chai = require "chai"
exports.mocha = require "mocha"
exports.Q = require "q"
```

How can I then access the individual variables like they are global variables in the current file? So instead of doing something like requireVar.chai I can just type chai?

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using coffeescript, I recommend you use the [destructuring assignment](http://coffeescript.org/#destructuring) feature:

```
{chai, mocha, Q} = require 'some_module'

// use chai, mocha and Q for good stuff
```

Comment: yeah this is what I ended up using. It looks the cleanest, kind of wish there were a one-line I could use to pull these global variables in myself but oh well ...

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just do:

```
var requireVar = require('yourmod')
  , chai = requireVar.chai
  , mocha = requireVar.mocha
  , Q = requireVar.Q
  ;

//then use chai, mocha and Q afterwards
chai.hoo();
mocha.mon();
Q.tip();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you *really*, *really* wanted to do this, I suppose you could use `with`:

```
with (require('yourMod')) {
    // use chai, mocha etc.
}
```

Note that no-one likes `with` however, especially [Douglas Crockford](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/). In reality *using* `requireVar.chai` is **good**; it removes any ambiguity as to *where* `chai` originates from, and makes it easy to understand the structure of your code/ modules.

If you get bored typing `requireVar`, make it really short; `a.chai`.