# Need some clarification about commonJS modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, commonjs, browserify

I am using nodeJS, and usually, I do my module declaration and requires like that :

```
controller.js
    exports.getApp = {value : "value", funct: function(){}}
OR
    module.exports = {value : "value", funct: function(){}}

app.js
    var controller = require('./controller')
```

And that worked pretty well.

Now I wanted to use CommonJS on my client-side to, so I started using grunt-browserify to handle my requires before serving the JS to the client.

Currently I am doing this on client JS:

```
controller.js
    controller = {value : "value", funct: function(){}}
    module.exports = controller;

app.js
    var controller = require('./controller');
```

And that works as well, BUT only if controller is a global variable.

**If I used keyword "var" before declaring "controller" in controller.js, "controller" would be undefined in app.js**

Why is that ? Shouldn't the export be available in the exports object, wether it comes from a local or global variable inside the module?

Another problem : *I cannot require module B in module A if module B requires module A*. The require of module B in module A results in an empty object. Maybe I am not doing this correctly.

Comment: What options are you using with grunt-browserify? Could you send the output of grunt-browserify?

Comment: @katranci https://gist.github.com/Rayjax/10646251

Comment: I think the issue is your entry point is set to multiple files: `src: ['client/lib/*.js'],`. It should probably only be set to your entry point: `'client/lib/app.js'` otherwise it will compile every file in `client/lib/` to `client/build/lib.js` overwriting the previous.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pull Entire Module into current scope Node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14789875/pull-entire-module-into-current-scope-node-js)

Comment: @PaulSweatte not the same problem at all, I don't want to import a module's exports contents in the current scope, I just don't have the normal imports working as expected

Comment: @KyleRobinsonYoung it is because the lib/ folder contains non-commonJS libraries (jquery, backbone etc) so I use a browserify shim (the 'exports' part) to make them available in the rest of the app. My non-lib JS files are in app/, and app.js is my entry point

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem. As long as both app.js and controller.js are located under `client/app/` directory they would end up in the same bundle (`client/build/app.js`) and it should just work. It may help if you could include an un-minified version of the bundled js file in your question.

Comment: @Rayjax export should not be defined in that case because assignment is done by reference. Once you leave the local scope, the reference to `controller` is lost.

Comment: @Rayjax The [spec says:](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports) `Note that assigning the desired object to exports will simply rebind the local exports variable, which is probably not what you want to do. `